# WPF - Override event

Tags: wpf, events

I'm inheriting a third party control and need to add steps for some events.

My old xaml:

```
<ThirdPartyControl Sorting="ThirdPartyControl_Sorting" />
```

My new xaml:

```
<MyInheritedControl Sorting="ThirdPartyControl_Sorting" />
```

In my inherited control i would implement the new steps and route the event back normally. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your third party control provide protected and virtual OnSorting method? If so, you can override it and do whatever you want and then call base implementation:

```
protected override OnSorting(SortingEventArgs e)
{
   // Do your thing

   base.OnSorting(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With *base* you can always call the parent class from a inherited (child) object:

```
        void Init()
        {
            base.Init();
        }
```

Like you said you have to route the event back to the parent. But I don't think it can be done in XAML directly.
You can even pass on method parameters:

```
        void Init(int value)
        {
            base.Init(value);
        }
```